# Blazor Webassembly: CSS :host variables not applied

Tags: css, variables, blazor, host

I am working on a layout for a Blazor Webassembly component. (=Fat browser client, no server rendering)

The layout looks like this and **works as expected**:

```css
.grid 
{
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: black;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 10px 5vh calc(90vh - 20px) 5vh 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 10px 3vw calc(94vw - 20px) 3vw 10px;
    /*Blazor Special*/
    margin: -8px;
}
```

```css
.gridCellLogo 
{
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 2;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="gridCellLogo">
        @*Put your component here*@
    </div>
</div>
```

**However**, if I use CSS variables, they are not applied. *Look at* **--somecolor**

```css
:host
{
    --somecolor: green;
}

.grid {
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: var(--somecolor);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 10px 5vh calc(90vh - 20px) 5vh 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 10px 3vw calc(94vw - 20px) 3vw 10px;
    /*Blazor Special*/
    margin: -8px;
}
```

*My question:*

**Is my CSS wrong or is Blazor Webassembly not ready for CSS variables yet?**

Comment: I think you are maybe confusing `:host` with `:root` here? `:host` is used to apply styles to the Shadow DOM in Web Components, whereas `:root` is used to apply CSS properties to the root element which should work for you here.

Answer (score 7):

Are you using Blazor CSS Isolation? E.g., `MyComponent.razor.css`? If so, CSS Isolation does not support pseudo classes, variables, or any CSS that starts with a **single** colon `:`.

You will need to declare these variables in a non-compiled CSS file like the `app.css` under `wwwroot/css`.

Answer (score 2):

Blazor css Isolation doesn't use shadow DOM so the `:host` selector is not available.
You can define your variables on the `:root` selector and then override it with your custom value on a particular css class like this

```
<div class="grid my-warpper-class">
    <div class="gridCellLogo">
        @*Put your component here*@
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
:root
{
  --somecolor: red;
}

.my-wrapper-class
{
  --somecolor: green;
  /* blue here is a fallback in case --somecolor didn't exist */
  background-color: var(--somecolor, blue);
}

.gridCellLogo {
  background-color: var(--somecolor, green);
}
```

defining the `--somecolor` variable on the `:root` will make it available everywhere, when you can overwrite it in any other class like `my-wrapper-class`

in that case the wrapper class and the gridCellLogo will have different background colors

Comment: If you are not sure don't post answer but post this as a comment