# How to properly add css pseudo selectors to a Blazor project

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, dom-events, blazor

After failing to get `:focus` and `:hover` to work in a .razor file structured like

```
<style>
...
    .login-button :focus{
        outline: 0 !important;
    }
...
</style>

<div>
...
    <button class="login-button">Login</div>
...
</div>

@code {
...
}
```

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65978818/blazor-webassembly-css-host-variables-not-applied/66683207#66683207) which says that these types of css selectors don't work regularly in the file, or when put in the child .css class you can do for a .razor file.

They recommend putting the css in the wwwroot folder for it to function, but I am wondering if this is a workaround, or the proper method for utilizing selectors like these in Blazor?

Comment: You use .css files in wwwroot for things that might be re-used, or CSS localization (google it) for per-component styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's the spaces.  This works:

##### Test.razor

```
@page "/Test"
<h3>Test Page</h3>
<div class="m-5">
    <button class="login-button">Log In</button>
</div>
<style>
    .login-button:focus {
        outline: ridge !important;
    }
</style>
```

##### Test.razor.css

```
.login-button:hover {
    background-color: forestgreen;
}

/*.login-button:focus {
    outline: ridge !important;
}
*/
```

Take you choice:

- Inline will apply to all matches across the page.
- Isolation will only apply to the specific component.

Comment: I can't tell you how much this bothers me that the space was the issue... But thank you. And maybe this is a question for another place, but if I do a style block in a component, then use that component on a page, that's still isolation, correct? Even though it isn't in a separate .css file?